# JWT Secured REST APIs being called outside of Android app

Tags: android, security, https, jwt

I have a fairly popular android app with hundreds of daily users. My app requires login flow that vends back a JWT token. The token is then used in the headers for other REST calls to some APIs I have hosted in the cloud. Each of these APIs confirm the authenticity of the token before responding.

Recently I've found out that some folks have managed to reverse engineer my app and are calling the APIs using tools like Postman. I'm assuming they discovered the auth flow by using APK decompiling tools. This is causing issues as it creates an uneven playing field for legitimate users.

I'm wondering what approach I can take to solve this problem either by detecting violators so I can ban them, or preventing it altogether.

Thanks

Comment: Invalidate all tokens, have your tokens expire more often, ensure you pin your SSL certificate and always use https requests, use cookies too, etc. But ultimately, if I have a JWT token and I look at your network traffic, then I can impersonate you. However, if you use a server-side generated value, and then you send that in the body of your encrypted request, it's going to be harder to spoof. It's a tough world, balancing between too much "security" (and sometimes through obscurity) and annoying your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your Problem Origins

> Recently I've found out that some folks have managed to reverse engineer my app and are calling the APIs using tools like Postman.

You problem may have origin in Reverse Engineering in conjunction with the use of an Instrumentation Framework at runtime, or by doing a MitM attack.

### Reverse Engineer

> Recently I've found out that some folks have managed to reverse engineer my app and are calling the APIs using tools like Postman. I'm assuming they discovered the auth flow by using APK decompiling tools.

So yes an attacker can reverse engineer your APK and then understand your work flow, and for that they can use an Open Source tool, like the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF):

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

Using this tool or another one to de-compile your APK, they can understand what method returns the JWT token, and then at runtime they can hook an instrumentation framwework, like Frida or Xposed to this method to be able to extract the JWT token, this in a device they control.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

Another more sophisticated approach that can be used by an attacker is to setup a captive portal for free WiFi in a public space, where they may trick the user into install another mobile app that have embedded an instrumentation framework, that will extract the JWT token and send it to a Command and Control Server(C&CS). Later they can used the C&CS to launch automated attacks with the stolen JWT tokens or just perform manual attacks against your APIs as the genuine user.

[Command and Control Server](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/definition/command-and-control-server):

> A command-and-control [C&C] server is a computer controlled by an attacker or cybercriminal which is used to send commands to systems compromised by malware and receive stolen data from a target network. Many campaigns have been found using cloud-based services, such as webmail and file-sharing services, as C&C servers to blend in with normal traffic and avoid detection.

### MitM Attack

> and are calling the APIs using tools like Postman.

The easiest way to grab a JWT token is for the attacker to perform a MitM attack in a device he controls, and then he can just launch automated or manual attacks.

A Open Source proxy tool for MitM attacks is the [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/):

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

You can see how to use it to extract a secret from a request in the article I wrote [Steal that API key with a MitM Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

Launching a MitM attack with the use of a captive portal is also possible, and here the attacker will trick the user to download its own certificates to the user device, but since Android API level 24 your mobile app is only trusting on the system certificates, unless you explicit tell in the network security config file that it can trust in user supplied certificates. So if you don't have users in old devices and your app doesn't explicit opt-in to trust in user supplied certificates, you are safe against this attack.

## Possible Solutions

> I'm wondering what approach I can take to solve this problem either by detecting violators so I can ban them, or preventing it altogether.

You can go with basic API defenses or with some more advanced ones, but I think what you are in need is a Mobile App Attestation solution, but lets walk first each of your possible solutions, but before we dive in the possible solutions, lets' first fix a common lack of knowledge among developers.

### The Who vs What Is Accessing the API Server

A usual issue among developers is that they are not aware of the difference between **WHO** vs **WHAT** is accessing the API server, and this is crucial to understand how you can defend against API attacks vs Mobile App attacks.

For a better understanding off the difference between **WHO** vs **WHAT** is accessing your API server, I recommend you to read [this section](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) of my article, but I will extract here some lines of it:

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.
>
> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

### The Basic API Security Defenses

Now that you understand the difference between **who** vs **what** is accessing your API server you may want to go an read [my article](https://dev.to/exadra37/the-top-6-mobile-api-protection-techniques-are-they-enough-3mhn) about the basic techniques to secure an API:

> In this article we will explore the most common techniques used to protect an API, including how important it is to use HTTPS to protect the communication channel between mobile app and API, how API keys are used to identify the mobile app on each API request, how user agents, captchas and IP addresses are used for bot mitigation, and finally how user authentication is important for the mobile security and api security. We will discuss each of these techniques and discuss how they impact the business risk profile, i.e. how easy they are get around.

### More Advanced API Security Defenses

You can start by read this series of articles on [Mobile API Security Techniques](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) to understand how API keys, HMAC, OAUTH and [certificate pinning](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android) can be used to enhance the security and at same time how they can be abused/defeated.

Afterwards and depending on your budget and resources you may employ an array of different approaches and techniques to defend your API server, and I will start to enumerate some of the most usual ones.

You can start with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by implementing a Mobile App Attestation solution that attests the integrity of your mobile app and device its running on before any request is made to the API server.

### Mobile App attestation

Finally if you have the resources you can go even further, by building your own [Mobile APP Attestation](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-protect-against-certificate-pinning-bypassing#mobile-app-attestation) solution:

> The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to authenticate what is sending the requests, thus only responding to requests coming from genuine mobile app instances and rejecting all other requests from unauthorized sources.
>
> In order to know what is sending the requests to the API server, a Mobile App Attestation service, at run-time, will identify with high confidence that your mobile app is present, has not been tampered/repackaged, is not running in a rooted device, has not been hooked into by an instrumentation framework(Frida, xPosed, Cydia, etc.), and is not the object of a Man in the Middle Attack (MitM). This is achieved by running an SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device it is running on.
>
> On a successful attestation of the mobile app integrity, a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud know. In the case that attestation fails the JWT token is signed with an incorrect secret. Since the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, it is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the app has been tampered with, is running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is the target of a MitM attack.
>
> The mobile app must send the JWT token in the header of every API request. This allows the API server to only serve requests when it can verify that the JWT token was signed with the shared secret and that it has not expired. All other requests will be refused. In other words a valid JWT token tells the API server that what is making the request is the genuine mobile app uploaded to the Google or Apple store, while an invalid or missing JWT token means that what is making the request is not authorized to do so, because it may be a bot, a repackaged app or an attacker making a MitM attack.
>
> A great benefit of using a Mobile App Attestation service is its proactive and positive authentication model, which does not create false positives, and thus does not block legitimate users while it keeps the bad guys at bay.

## Summary

In my opinion the best solution is defense in depth, by applying as many layers as you can, so that you increase the time, effort and skill-set necessary to by pass all your security layers, thus keeping at bay the script kids and the majority of hackers from abusing your service.

So you should employ has much techniques as possible in both sides of the equation, mobile app and API, like the ones you have learned when reading the articles I have linked: HTTPS, API keys, User Agents, Captchas, Rate Limiting, OAuth, HMAC, Certificate Pinning, Code Obfuscation, JNI/NDK to hide secretes, WAF, UBA, etc.

In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

### Going the Extra Mile

I would strongly recommend you, to also take a look into the
[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

Comment: This was a fantastic read. Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: Always makes me happy to know that someone found useful my insights and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to guarantee a request is coming from your app. Anyone with access to your apk will be able to decompile and reveal any embedded secrets/logic.

Are there any indications from the behavior of the users that might make a fake stand out from normal play? Without details on the game it is hard to suggest an approach, but you may be able to flag suspicious activity and ban those users server-side.